# in python , result file not contain all these values

Tags: python

I used this code to extract data form website but it is not enough to get all data I need

also I can not catch the `sku` value which is **buried** at the end of the page **with other valuable data** at the end of the page (which I do not how to get it)

```
{"offer_code":"dd3125025109fb4d","sku":"N15614801A","sku_config":"N15614801A","brand":null,"name":"AirPods Strap White","plp_specifications":{},"price":4.4,"sale_price":1.3,"url":"airpods-strap-white","image_key":"v1532025662/N15614801A_1","is_buyable":true,"flags":["fbn","prepaid"]},
```

**it will be very helpful to get the result file to contain all these values (which is what I am looking for)**

```
price,title,sku,offer_code,brand,sale_price
```

This is the python code I use

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

number_of_threads = 6
headers = "price,title,sku, \n"

def extract_data_from_url_func(url):
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    page_soup = soup(response.text, "html.parser")


        output_list = [price,title,sku,]
        output = output + ",".join(output_list) + "\n"
        print(output)

    return output

with open("speednoon.txt", "r") as fr:
    URLS = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), fr.readlines()))




with open(out_filename, "w", encoding='utf-8-sig') as fw:
  fw.write(headers)
  for response in responses:
      fw.write(response + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a drawback of using class names with numbers. They may vary with each product. So, here would be a simple answer to the question:

Note: I am not writing the whole code. Just filter part.
Note : Instead of html.parser use lxml. To use that, type `import lxml`.

```
title = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'name'})
for i in title:
     print("Title: "+i.text)
```

For the price:

```
price = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'sellingPrice'})
for i in price:
    print("Price: "+i.text)
```

for the SKU:

```
sku = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'gridView'})
for i in sku:
    sku_num = i.find('a')['href'].split('/')
    print(sku_num[3])
```

for the offer_code:

```
code = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'gridView'})
for i in sku:
    code_num = i.find('a')['href'].split('/')
    print(code_num[4].split("=")[1])
```

for the brand:
I can't find it. Please specify where the brand name is.

for sale_price:
Sale price is the price i already mentioned. If you mean the original price, it is in the class: "preReductionPrice". Grab it with .text

Comment: @user3679776 My pleasure. Let me know if you want any other help.